# React Context for event

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have the following context:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createContext } from "react";

type UserModifcationContextType = {
  onEdit?: (objectId: number) => void;
  onDelete?: (objectId: number) => void;
};

export const UserModificationContext = createContext<UserModifcationContextType>({
  onDelete: undefined,
  onEdit: undefined
});


export const UserModificationContextProvider: React.FC<UserModifcationContextType> = ({
  onDelete,
  onEdit
}) => {
  return (<UserModificationContext.Provider value={{ onDelete, onEdit }
  } />
  );
}
```

The reason I am using this is because I need to refresh the user's data in a parent component when one of many deeply nested sub components modifies a user. For example a user can delete another user by either right clicking and selecting "Delete User" from a custom right click menu or they can click a delete button.
The issue is that the parent of the custom right click menu needs to also listen for deletes so that the custom right click menu is closed on delete. My question is should I store an event emitter in the custom context or is there some other way I haven't considered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store your functions in context. If the references to your functions never change after initialization, you could also export / import it into whatever you component you want.